# Assigning stream to a variable from getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, loops, stream, vue.js, webrtc

`URL.createObjectURL(stream)` is being deprecated in favore of `video.srcObject = stream` which should be used instead.

I'm working on a solution where I am using a frontend framework *Vue.js* and I'm binding my variables to the video element as follows:

```js
:src = "video_src"
```

where

```js
video_src = URL.createObjectURL(stream)
```

And in some cases I have multiple `URL.createObjectURL(stream)` in an array looped through using the `v-for` construct.

Is `video.srcObject = stream` the only way to get the exact element?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I just added a new component dedicated to assign `srcObject` but someone also answered on my question on `Vue Forum`, doing a vue directive (not yet tested but I think it would work also).

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-assign-property-of-an-element-via-v-for/19859/3